# Jquery AutoScroll Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a one page design and want to have an auto scroll effect when a nav link is clicked. Not sure why the scrolling effect is not working. I added the alert function to see if `$(sectionID).offset().top` is returning a value and it is. So if someone can explain the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8t881403/

html:

```
<div class="sub-nav">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#why-cs">Why CS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#learning-experience">Learning Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#spartan-success">Spartan Success</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {

  autoScroll();

});

function autoScroll() {
    $('.sub-nav a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sectionID = $(this).attr('href');
        alert($(sectionID).offset().top);
        $('html body').animate({ scrollTop: $(sectionID).offset().top
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you add fiddle for this?

Comment: Is your "sub-nav" div inside another scrollable div?

Answer (score -1):

```
var div = $('.sub-nav');
setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    div.scrollTop(pos + 2);
}, 200)
```

Comment: Please provide a short explanation as to what your code is doing, don't simply dump it

Comment: This is not an answer to answer the question.

Comment: Please read the comments and improve the answer with more explanation